# Why does only the second function run when two functions with the same name exist

Tags: javascript, function

I have these following functions.

```
function a(obj)
{
    console.log("function 1 "+obj);
}

function a(x)
{
    console.log("function 2 "+"3");
}

a(1);
```

Why is always the second function running? Why not the first one?

Comment: the second overwrites the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have two functions *in the same scope*, with the same name. The second will replace the first. This is why the first one is never executed.

If you wish to overload the function, you can do so by checking the type(s) of the argument immediately within the function. As an example, consider the following:

```js
function a ( x ) {
    var output;
    switch ( typeof x ) {
        case "string" :
            output = "foo";
            break;
        case "object" :
            output = "bar";
            break;
        default:
            output = typeof x;
    }
    console.log( output );
}
```

Comment: @zerkms It must be hard for you to understand but yes I am already working in strict mode, hence was the question to understand why such a thing doesn't throw error in strict mode. But thanks for the concern. Nevermind.

Comment: @AngularHarsh I'd think the rationale why this isn't an error in strict mode might be that this is a feature of the language that could be useful in certain cases. Most of the time, though, this would be a source of errors and might be something that could be picked up by the various linters available. Just speculating though.

Comment: Yes. This could be one of the possible rationale.

Comment: @angularharsh Just a tip for the future: if you already know that it doesn't throw an error, don't ask does it throw an error. Ask *why* it doesn't throw an error. You'll get less snark and better answers.

Answer (score 1):

As the second function is declared after the first it overrides the first. Javascript doesn't care that the parameters are different, it only goes by the function name.